# How do I write data to my firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I need to write data onto my firebase real time database, it has all read and write enabled but the code (on a web page) does not work?

I have a simple reference to the database and a write function but it gives me the error of app.database() is not a function, which variable am I supposed to reference for it?

```
<script type="module" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.1/firebase-app.js";
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx",
    appId: "xxx"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  function writeUserData(userId, name, email) {
    app.database().ref('users').set(ref(db, 'users/' + userId), {
    username: name,
    email: email
    });
  }
  
  writeUserData(1, "tester", "test@gmail.com");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Import` `getFirestore` and try to reference the `firestore database` from it.

```
<script type="module" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.1/firebase-app.js";
  import {getFirestore, collection, addDoc} 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.1/firebase-firestore.js'
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx",
    appId: "xxx"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = getFirestore(app);

  async function writeUserData(userId, name, email) {
    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
      userId,
      username,
      email
    });
  }
  
  writeUserData(1, "tester", "test@gmail.com");
</script>
```

Comment: it now says db.ref is not a function, also I should mention that this is for the realtime database

Comment: You are adding a user into a collection called 'users', right?

Comment: Yes I am doing that

Comment: I have updated the answer, try to use it now.

Comment: it now says 'POST xxxxxxxx net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT'

Comment: it turns out that it was because of my ad blocker, however it still does not write anything but creates no errors

Comment: Check the firebase console, it should work.

Comment: how to do I find the console?

Comment: on the firebase website. Go to the firestore database.

Comment: Wow, wonderful.
Please accept the answer so that it helps others get the correct solution.